# Extending Flow typed class generic parameter

Tags: generics, flowtype, extends

I have a concrete type based on generic `Component` type:

```
type Props = {||}
type State = {|
  count: number
|}
class MyComponent extends Component<Props, State> {
  state = {
    count: 42
  }
}
```

Now, I would like to make `MyComponent` state extensible, so I could do something like this:

```
type State = {|
  name: string
|}
class MyNamedComponent extends MyComponent<State> {
  state = {
    name: 'Ford'
  }
}
```

I tried using type intersection like so:

```
class MyComponent<S> extends Component<Props, S & State> {
```

but it does not work with Flow ([Demo](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoAlgWwA5wE4AuyYAhgM5gBKApiQMZFR5yZgDketDbA3KqgQCe2amAAKzbBQC8YAN4AfBQF8+QkWADKBEgVGzFqMGDpwArgDsCALjAWzmAEbU8qFX1R0Y5CgFlBAMIsuBbUVgA8mgB8YNQAHnoWACYUNPQEAHRBOHChERJwUgA0WmAAZFo6ejFyRmBkVfrydcamljZgACwATHXKqP1AA)).

Any suggestions how to accomplish my goal?

Comment: Works for me: https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoAlgWwA5wE4AuyYAhgM5gBKApiQMZFR5yZgDketDbA3KqgQCe2amAAKzbBQC8YAN4AfBQF8+QkWADKBEgVGzFKvqjoxyFAEIAeAKoA+MNQAeegHYATCjXoEAdAGEWXFdqVwIrCTgpABowGzAAMi0dPQc5ZX4gA

Comment: For me it does not: https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoAlgWwA5wE4AuyYAhgM5gBKApiQMZFR5yZgDketDbA3KqgQCe2amAAKzbBQC8YAN4AfBQF8+QkWADKBEgVGzFqMGDpwArgDsCALjAWzmAEbU8qFX1R0Y5CgFlBAMIsuBbUVgA8mgB8YNQAHnoWACYUNPQEAHRBOHChERJwUgA0WmAAZFo6ejFyRmBkVfrydcamljZgACwATHXKqP1AA